# CefSharp: force re-render

Tags: winapi, cefsharp, managed-c++

There is a Managed C++ application. Some of its C++ (MFC) views host a WinForm's version of CefSharp. It shows everything OK.
But, there is annoying bug: when Cefsharp's window where hidden by another window, and then that window are closed, then CefSharp's window becomes completely blank. If try to resize this window or move it then CefSharp engine re-draw html content and everything is OK. But if we do nothing it stays blank forever. Is it possible somehow to force CefSharp to re-draw content on Activate or so event?
I tried to google, bot not successed ...

Comment: You can try calling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow using the browser's window handle, likely has to be called on the CEF UI thread. You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/b72d41353e6e9c964a51ea66c5aaad2527f9a383/CefSharp.WinForms/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L57 as a reference.

Comment: Looks like chromium does something similar internally for reference https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=1552;drc=32f574f6df1d37b0d9ed765fe138270414d79e49?q=ForceRedrawWindow&ss=chromium